# How can I invoke the System() function inside a function in my c++ code?

Tags: c++, file, system

I'm coming to invoke then function every thing goes well

```
int status = system("./my_exe_file input output");
```

But when i wanted to invoke it inside a function, i've got a little problem manipulating files:

```
void call(std::string f){
  FILE *in = fopen (in, "r");  
  int status = system("./my_exe_file f output");   
}
```

Can any one tell me what to do?

Comment: You'll need to concatenate your strings together...

Comment: What to do about what? What's the problem? What's the question?

Comment: @EJP: OP wants to insert `f` inside the string passed to `system`.

Comment: What is `FILE *in = fopen (in, "r");` supposed to do? It makes no sense this way. Shouldn't the right `in` be `f`?

Comment: @MatsPetersson All I can see here is 'I've got a little problem manipulating files'. This is not a problem description. Code doesn't even appear to compile.

Comment: It is operating system specific. On POSIX systems like Linux you should consider using [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) if you care about the output of that command. And your question shows a lot of confusion (you need to build the command string at runtime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to concatenate strings by simply write their variable name inside a string literal, like you did.

To concatenate 2 or more strings, you can use the `+`/`+=` operator of `std::string`.

```
std::string command = std::string("./my_exe_file ") + f + " output";
system( command.c_str() );
```

Note that the first literal `"./my_exe_file "` has to be encapsulated in a string, since you can add string literals to strings, and strings to strings, but not a string to a string literal.

Note also, that in the second line the `system()` call wants a C string (`char*`). `std::string::c_str()` gives you the C string representation of the `std::string`.